# (Softlayer API) How can I get NAS/FTP storage list for an account?

Tags: ftp, ibm-cloud-infrastructure, nas

I've tried getNasNetworkStorage(), getNetworkStorge() etc. But I couldn't find storages named IBMN87XXXX although I actually have 3 NAS/FTP.

```
    Account.Service service = Account.service(client);
    service.withMask().nasNetworkStorage();
    service.withMask().nasNetworkStorage().billingItem();
    service.withMask().nasNetworkStorage().billingItem().orderItem();
    service.withMask().nasNetworkStorage().billingItem().orderItemId();

    Account account = service.getObject();

    List<Storage> storages = account.getNasNetworkStorage();
```

Answer (score 0):

The [getNasNetworkStorag](http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Account/getNasNetworkStorage)e method must return the NAS/FAT storages, also you can try the [getNetworkStorage](http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Account/getNetworkStorage) method which will return all the storages in your account. In case you are not able to see the storage, even using the getNetworkStorage method, this is likely because the API account you are using does not have permissions to list the object storages and I recomend you to check your permissions with the account administrator.